# Getting STM32 Nucleo F030R8 to communicate with RX and TX pins

Tags: stm32, uart, mbed

I'm having issues trying to get this Nucleo to send commands or receive commands using the online mbed compiler.
As a starter step, I am trying to connect the rx and tx pin on my Nucleo to try to send a command to itself and display it using serial display. Could anyone provide some assistance in the matter? I seem to be getting nowhere on this and online searches haven't yielded many promising results.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with the [system.reactive] tag? That relates to Microsoft's Reactive Framework.

Comment: No, i put RX as in the RX pin...and it just made it system.reacrive my apologies. There it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there are 2 UARTS, I was using the first one and that one was being used by the USBTX and USBRX.  So i just used pins D2 and D8, the UART2 pins so there was no conflict.